# PHPUnit Test Suite doesn't work

Tags: php, testing, phpunit, typo3, extbase

**This is the method that has to be tested with PHPUnit Test**

```php
public function newAction(\ReRe\Rere\Domain\Model\Modul $newModul = NULL) {
    if ($this->request->hasArgument(self::RETURNMODUL)) {
        $this->view->assignMultiple(array(self::MODULNAME => $this->request->getArgument(self::RETURNMODUL),
            self::MODULNUMMER => $this->request->getArgument(self::MODULNUMMER),
            self::GUELTIGKEITSZEITRAUM => $this->request->getArgument(self::GUELTIGKEITSZEITRAUM),
            self::FACHNAME => $this->request->getArgument(self::FACHNAME),
            self::FACHNUMMER => $this->request->getArgument(self::FACHNUMMER),
            self::PRUEFER => $this->request->getArgument(self::PRUEFER)));
    } else {
        $this->view->assignMultiple(array('newModul' => $newModul, self::GUELTIGKEITSZEITRAUM => $this->request->getArgument(self::GUELTIGKEITSZEITRAUM)));
    }
}
```

**the code below was created automatically from PHPUnit Test Suite**

```php
public function newActionAssignsTheGivenModulToView() {
    $modul = new \ReRe\Rere\Domain\Model\Modul();

    $view = $this->getMock(self::VIEWINTERFACE);
    $view->expects($this->once())->method(self::ASSIGN)->with('newModul', $modul);
    $this->inject($this->subject, 'view', $view);

    $this->subject->newAction($modul);
}
```

But it just doesn't work. PHPUnit didn't show any comments why the test code isn't functioning.. I really need some help, and every helps will be very appreciated since I don't have single knowledge in PHPUnit Test.

Comment: Read the PHPUnit documentation.

Answer (score 0):

PHPUnit find test in class with suffix "Test" and test cases are public methods with prefix "test", as you can see in [documentation](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html) and [organizing tests](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/organizing-tests.html)

> Note If you point the PHPUnit command-line test runner to a directory
>   it will look for *Test.php files.

Try

```
class ActionTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{

    public function testNewAction(\ReRe\Rere\Domain\Model\Modul $newModul = NULL) 
    {
        if ($this->request->hasArgument(self::RETURNMODUL)) {
            $this->view->assignMultiple(array(self::MODULNAME => $this->request->getArgument(self::RETURNMODUL),
            self::MODULNUMMER => $this->request->getArgument(self::MODULNUMMER),
            self::GUELTIGKEITSZEITRAUM => $this->request->getArgument(self::GUELTIGKEITSZEITRAUM),
            self::FACHNAME => $this->request->getArgument(self::FACHNAME),
            self::FACHNUMMER => $this->request->getArgument(self::FACHNUMMER),
            self::PRUEFER => $this->request->getArgument(self::PRUEFER)));
        } else {
            $this->view->assignMultiple(array('newModul' => $newModul, self::GUELTIGKEITSZEITRAUM => $this->request->getArgument(self::GUELTIGKEITSZEITRAUM)));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The class name does not require a 'Test' suffix.

Comment: @Drumbeg, I added link to organizing tests

Comment: Was just trying to point out that adding 'Test' as a suffix to the class name is not mandatory.

Comment: I did change the inheration from my classtest, now it inherits the PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase as you said, but with this change I can't test my code anymore. just with inheration to \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Tests\UnitTestCase I can test it.
As info: I use the PHPUnit Test in Typo3 Backend, and the project is an extbase project.

Comment: @Nicolas Tedjadharma, the implementation worked? If yes, you can mark the answer as acepted, upvote and open new question with more info. Did you read the documentation? 
About the more tests, you can extends news class test and write new tests case.

Comment: no, it didn't. It says Argument 1 passed to TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Repository::__construct() must implement interface TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Object\ObjectManagerInterface, none given, called in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/typo3conf/ext/phpunit/Composer/vendor/phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects/src/Framework/MockObject/Generator.php on line 288 and defined

Comment: @acfreitas, you can see the complete code in our GitHub

https://github.com/TeamProjektWS1415/rere

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, You can precede the test-method with a php comment and a @test annotation. This way the method can keep its arbitrary name, and it does not need to prefixed with "test".

```
/**
* @test
*/
public function newActionAssignsTheGivenModulToView() {
    ///...
}
```